# Does ReactJS UseEffect hook instantly run when a dependency is triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchWithRetry(backend_link).then((res) => res.json()).then((res) => {
      setData(res);
      setLoading(false);
      
    })
},[didPost]);
```

Looking at this sample code for `useEffect`, does this trigger when didPost (useState object) has a state change? Also, when `useEffect` is triggered in general, does the code instantly stop in its tracks and run the `useEffect` lines then go back to where it left off?

I have tried to change around the values in the second `useEffect` parameter but I feel like I am just not understanding how the hook functions actually.

Comment: The effect would be triggered on the next render in which the dependency has changed.  Nothing "stops in its tracks, does something, and goes back to where it left off".  Code executes in the order in which it's invoked, always.  It's not really clear to me what led you to this question, is something in your code not working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The useEffect hook in ReactJS runs after the first render and after every update. When a dependency is triggered, the useEffect hook will run on the next render, not instantly. This means that the code does not stop in its tracks and run the useEffect lines then go back to where it left off. Instead, the useEffect hook is called after the component has been updated.

In the sample code you provided, the useEffect hook has a dependency array [didPost], which means that it will only run when the value of didPost changes. When didPost changes, the component will re-render and the useEffect hook will run after the render is complete.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use the `useEffect(fn, [])` construct to reproduce the `componentDidMount` functionality, it is not the exact equivalent of `componentDidMount`. Namely, it, unlike `componentDidMount`, captures properties and state. Therefore, even inside the callback, you will see the original properties and state. If you want to see the latest version of something, you can write it in the ref link. But usually there is an easier way to structure the code, so it is not necessary to do this. Keep in mind that the mental effects model is different from the one applicable to componentDidMount and other methods of the component lifecycle. Therefore, trying to find exact equivalents can do more harm than good. In order to work productively, you need to, so to speak, "think with effects." The basis of their mental model is closer to the implementation of synchronization than to responding to the events of the component lifecycle.

Comment: I'm an new to react and this is actually my first project, with all the debugging and googling I have done I have seen multiple people mentioning how there are different structures react can use. It seems like many say that using "componentdidmount" is outdated but I was confused by this. Is there an article or place which documents the most updated methodology to using react? If you know something like that a link would be appreciated.